# Display day name when date is selected from datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, html

when we select any desire date, php code should convert day name accordingly.

our working code to display date is here.

```
<div class="togo datemark sidebord datepicker2" iditem="datepicker3"><input type="text" readonly
class="normalinput auto-focus hand-cursor form-control b-r-0"
id="datepicker3" placeholder="Select Date"
value="<?php echo @$onw_rndw_segment_search_params['depature'] ?>" name="depature" required /></div>
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. It's unclear what the problem is here, your post is vague and seems to be incomplete - I don't see any actual question, only a rather vague set of requirements. What have you researched? What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: You can use date() function along with the "l" format specifier in php

Answer (score -3):

To convert a given date to the corresponding day name in PHP, you can use the date() function along with the "l" format specifier. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
$date = "2023-06-20";
$dayName = date("l", strtotime($date));
echo $dayName;
```

In this code, we have a variable $date representing the desired date. The strtotime() function converts the date string to a Unix timestamp, which is then passed to the date() function with the "l" format specifier. The "l" specifier returns the full day name (e.g., "Monday", "Tuesday", etc.).

When you run this code, it will output the corresponding day name for the given date, which in this case would be "Tuesday" for the date "2023-06-20".

Feel free to replace the $date variable with any desired date value to get the corresponding day name.

Comment: sir , date dynamically change its depend on selection of desire date. for more look here https://www.dealtravel.in/

Comment: <div class="togo datemark sidebord datepicker1" iditem="datepicker2"><input type="text" readonly="" class="normalinput auto-focus hand-cursor form-control b-r-0 hasDatepicker" id="datepicker2" placeholder="Select Date" value="29-06-2023" name="depature" required=""></div> -----could take string value from code(29-06-2023) and display day name to another div

Comment: @MIH if you want to do it without reloading the page you would need javascript for that. Nothing to do with php. Go and read how to get the day name from a date in javascript...someone will have done it before.

Comment: can anyone help with such code

Comment: var dateInput = document.getElementById("datepicker2-input").value;

var dateComponents = dateInput.split("-");

// Create a new Date object with the specified year, month (zero-based), and day
var date = new Date(dateComponents[2], dateComponents[1] - 1, dateComponents[0]);

// Get the day name from the Date object
var dayName = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "long" });

// Display the day name in the target div
var dayNameContainer = document.getElementById("dayNameContainer");
dayNameContainer.textContent = dayName;

Comment: dear sir , can have compete code

Comment: @MIH this site is not a free write-my-code service. You're expected to make some effort to solve it, or adapt things you find online. Then you can come to us if you get stuck on something specific within your attempt. We are volunteers here...your time is not more important than ours. As I said above, I would be very surprised if no-one in the entire internet has tried to get a date from a datepicker, and then get the day name from that date, using JS. I doubt it needs repeating or re-writing.  Have you actually looked at your search engine yet?? See also [ask]

Comment: @MIH also, what do you think is incomplete about aleksandar's code anyway? Did you try it? What was the specific problem?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since you posted 7 answers today, most or all of which appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.